# Geopandas causes recursion error in pyinstaller

Tags: python, geopandas

When trying to turn to exe a py file this happens:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

It turns out after a lot of trial and error by deleting libraries that may cause issues that after removing `geopandas` it finally created the exe.

So the problem now is how to make it work WITH geopandas in it because it is important for my program.

Comment: Do you know if it is actually due to geopandas itself, or with one of its dependencies? (shapely, fiona, ..)

Comment: the only thing I know is that when I removed the library it worked.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42419584/2799098) about increasing the recursion limit may be helpful.

Comment: I have already done it but it didn't fix it. Actually it looked like it didn't affect it. I tried both with spec file and the py and it didn't do anything.